# Could someone explain this algorithm that uses raycasting?

Tags: c++, algorithm

http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/

It's the first part:

Calculate the angles where walls begin or end.

Cast a ray from the center along each angle.

Fill in the triangles generated by those rays.

I'm doing something like this:

```
    vector<float> angles;

    for(int i = 0; i < polygonCoordinates.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; i < polygonCoordinates[i].size(); j++)
        {
            angles.push_back(AngleBetweenPoints(LIGHT_POSITION, polygonCoordinates[i][j]));
        }
    }
```

Where polygonCoordinates is a 2D vector, basically each polygon is a vector of Point2D structs and all polygons are inside a bigger vector.So after I find the angles, how do I proceed?Why do I need raycasting?How will that help me generate the "light polygon"?

Comment: How else do you know what the bounds of the polygon are?

Comment: Raycasting is needed to determine which polygon surfaces are occluded or visible. The vector from any point on visible surface to the center(viewer) will not pass through any other polygons. Because they are polygons, you don't need to cast for every point, just the vertices. Thats what the author of the article means by light polygon.

Comment: @BWG but how do I know which one is occluded?Do I do some ray to line intersection test for each polygon to check if there are points behind the walls?What if 2 walls are visible?

Comment: ok so for each point I send a ray and then I intersect this ray with everything else and if any intersection test returns true I check if what it intersects is closer to the light source?

Comment: I'm working on it right now. I'll answer in a minute or more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things first: Sort your angles and their corresponding vertices from least to greatest.

Start with your viewer 'aiming' to the left, and store the nearest visible point (which happens to be on the wall) in tmpPoint or something like that.

[image]

Then, you go through your list of angles you calculated. You are going to sweep out the whole area of the screen, clockwise (do this by iterating through your list of sorted angles). The first ray you are testing is the bottom left of the little rectangle (it has the lowest angle that you calculated). The nearest visible point is on the left wall somewhere. Your visible triangle list, add the triangle formed by the viewer, tmpPoint, and the point you just found. (see picture)
Finally, store that point in tmpPoint.

[image]

The next point we check is the upper left of the little rectangle. Here  is where we really need to check for visibility. The nearest point is the visible one. (see picture) Then, add your triangle (composed again of the point you just found, the viewer, and tmpPoint). Just repeat this process over and over, and you will eventually fill your whole screen with triangles representing visibility.

[image]

I hope this helps. I made some nice pseudocode, but I was doing it wrong, so here are just the graphics. :P

Edit:
So you have your verticy array all calculated out, and by calculated I mean visibility of the rays. What you do is something almost like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < calculatedVertices.size()-1; i++) {
    triangle t = triangle(
        calculatedVertices[i],
        calculatedVertices[i+1],
        centerViewer);
    triangleArray.add(t);
}
//the loop above misses one triangle, so just add the last one
triangle final = triangle(
    calculatedVertices[0]
    calculatedVertices[calculatedVertices.size()-1],
    centerViewer);
triangleArray.add(final);
```

This nearly fully works, except for one terrible issue:

[image]

You see, when you have your far-wall cast triangle, the intersection should occur on the wall, but when you have your triangle cast to the rectangle, the intersection should occur on the rectangle itself. If the intersections don't occur in this manner, this will happen:

[image]

I'm not entirely sure if this is an actual problem, or if its just something i'm thinking of, but a way you can solve it is by adding a slight bias (of your intersection detection) towards your other vertex, if you know what I mean. That should fix this problem.

Comment: ok this may sound dumb, but I'm still having a little trouble..so here is what I do:

1.Make an array with all vertices(all the vertices of the polygons + the 4 vertices of the walls) and sort it by the angles
2.Make an array of lines(generated from all the polygon vertices)
3.Iterate the array of vertices and for each vertex, iterate all lines and see if the ray intersects any line and if it does, check if the intersection point is closer to the light than the vertex
4...this is where I get stuck do I need some for(int i = 0; i < ??; +=3) loop to generate the triangles?

Comment: Not dumb at all. It is quite a difficult task. I will edit my answer to explain. You are on the right track though.

Comment: ok I almost did it, I actually ended up having the final problem(the one you marked in red) just what exactly did you mean by a bias?I'm not sure what you meant.

Comment: a bias means, shifting something one way or another to eliminate imprecision in computations. This might not quite be an example of bias, but when you compare two floating points, you can't just use ==, you have to have a small margin of error. So in your case, you might just want to slightly shift each ray towards one another, to make sure the right collisions are met. But only by a little bit! Otherwise your visibility triangles might have pixel wide gaps.